# tkinter images representing objects leave screen

Tags: python, image, tkinter, coordinates, move

im building a tile-to-tile walking game in tkinter, and when working on the pathfinding of the enemies on screen, they use to walk out of the screen, nevermind of the bounderies i set to them.
More frustrating that if i just enable the individual "directions", it works, only if all four of them are active then the images walk out of the canvas.
i use canvas grid, root.after(), and update_idletasks().
Is it possible that there are miniature differences when rendering an image object? Help appriciated. 4 hours of repetative simple-tasks, and im still stuck at this:

```
def move(self):

    movements = []

    up = self.move_up()
    down = self.move_down()
    left = self.move_left()
    right = self.move_right()

    if up:
        movements.append('U')
    if down:
        movements.append('D')
    if left:
        movements.append('L')
    if right:
        movements.append('R')

    if len(movements) == 0:
        return
    else:
        t = random.randint(0,len(movements)-1)
        print(t)
        destination = movements[t]
        if destination == 'U':
            canvas.move(self.image, 0, -72)
            self.testBoxY = self.testBoxY - 72
            self.a -= 1
        if destination == 'D':
            canvas.move(self.image, 0, + 72)
            self.testBoxY = self.testBoxY + 72
            self.a += 1
        if destination == 'L':
            canvas.move(self.image, -72 , 0)
            self.b -= 1
            self.testBoxX = self.testBoxX - 72
        if destination == 'R':
            canvas.move(self.image, +72, 0)
            self.b += 1
            self.testBoxX = box.testBoxX + 72

def move_up(self):
    try:
        if self.testBoxY == 36:
            return 
        if grid[self.a - 1][self.b] == 1:
            return
    except IndexError:
        return
    else:
        return True

def move_down(self):
    try:
        if self.testBoxY == 684:
            return
        if grid[self.a + 1][self.b] == 1:   
            return
    except IndexError:
        return
    else:
        return True

def move_left(self):
    try:
        if self.testBoxX == 36:
            return
        if grid[self.a][self.b - 1] == 1:
            return
    except IndexError:
        return
    else:
        return True

def move_right(self):
    try:
        if self.testBoxX == 684:
            return
        if grid[self.a][self.b + 1] == 1:
            return
    except IndexError:
        return
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: you check `self.testBoxY == 36` but more safe could be `self.testBoxY <= 36`

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables and you will see if they are correct. You can also `print(self.testBoxX == 36)` to see if it gives True,

Comment: Since 72 does not evenly divide 684-32 = 652, it is guaranteed that the marker can go pass the boundary.  Hence the suggestion by @furas.  You could avoid pixel issues by using gridded labels with images.